# Java ActionListner not work correctly

Tags: java

Iam beginning my adventure with Java. I decide learn smth about swing. But i have problem with ActionListner (last method). I decide that, if user click on "+" on JLabel tekst1 show first number, and when user click on "Oblicz" in JLabel tektst2 show secend number, but it isn't working. After click "+" numer are adding to JLabel tekst1.
My method : ActionListnerB1, ActionListnerB2 are for tekst1
ActionListnerB11, ActionListnerB12 are for tekst2.
I have still another problem, when i open programm, i cant see certain buttons and JTextField, muss my window increase then decrease

My code:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Kalku extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
 JButton jeden,dwa,dodaj,oblicz;
 JTextField pasek;
 JLabel tekst1,tekst2;
 String licz1,licz2;
 public Kalku()
 {
     super("Kalkulator");
     this.setSize(500, 500);
     setLayout(null);
     setVisible(true);
     licz1="";
     licz2="";
     jeden = new JButton("1");
     jeden.setBounds(20, 400, 80, 20);
     add(jeden);
     dwa=new JButton("2");
     dwa.setBounds(100, 400, 80, 20);
     add(dwa);
     oblicz = new JButton("Oblicz");
     oblicz.setBounds(350, 360, 100, 40);
     add(oblicz);
     pasek = new JTextField();
     pasek.setBounds(100,120,200,30);
     add(pasek);
     pasek.setVisible(true);
     tekst1=new JLabel("Liczba1");
     tekst1.setBounds(400,120,50,50);
     add(tekst1);
     tekst2=new JLabel("Liczba 2");
     tekst2.setBounds(450,120,50,50);
     add(tekst2);
     dodaj=new JButton("+");
     dodaj.setBounds(20,250,80,20);
     add(dodaj);
     jeden.addActionListener(this);
     dwa.addActionListener(this);
     oblicz.addActionListener(this);
     dodaj.addActionListener(this);
 }
     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
           Kalku k1= new Kalku();    
     }
    public void ActionListnerB1(ActionEvent event)
    {
        if(event.getSource()==jeden)
        {
          licz1=licz1+"1";
        } 
    }
    public void ActionListnerB2(ActionEvent event)
    {
        if(event.getSource()==dwa)
        {
          licz1=licz1+"2";
        } 
    }

    public void ActionListnerB12(ActionEvent event)
    {
        if(event.getSource()==jeden)
        {
          licz2=licz2+"1";
        } 
    }
    public void ActionListnerB22(ActionEvent event)
    {
        if(event.getSource()==dwa)
        {
          licz2=licz2+"2";
        } 
    }
    public void WynikDod(String l1, String l2)
    {
        int li1=Integer.parseInt(licz1);
        int li2=Integer.parseInt(l2);
        int wyn=li1+li2;
        pasek.setText(Integer.toString(wyn));
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
        if(event.getSource()==oblicz)
        {
            tekst2.setText(licz2);
            pasek.setText("pusto");
            //Method WynikDod(() and show in pasek result
        }
        if(event.getSource()==dodaj)
        {
            ActionListnerB12(event);
            ActionListnerB22(event);
            tekst2.setText(licz2);
        }       
        if(event.getSource()!=dodaj & event.getSource()!=oblicz)
        {
            ActionListnerB1(event);
            ActionListnerB2(event);
            tekst1.setText(licz1);
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post only the relevant code. Nobody is going to look through all of that

Comment: Your code really needs some cleanup - try to adhere to java coding guidelines (e.g. like these: https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html). For example, almost all java developers start their method names with lower case letters and types with upper case letters. Also try to use names that are meaningful and convey their purpose.